# Получение оповещения о новых данных Android?

Tags: java, android, mysql, kotlin, firebase

Ситуация следующая
Уже есть готовый продукт и админка, которые не зависят от меня и вносят изменения в БД (MYSQL) для ясности примера предположим, что это посты с новостями.

Моё Android приложение должно автоматически получать новые новости из бд.
Я вижу несколько вариантов решения данной проблемы.

1. Стучаться в бд каждые 5 секунд и проверять на наличие новых записей ( выглядит не эффективно и не правильно)
2. Написать триггер в базе данных который отправляет http запрос и каким-то магическим образом ловить его с телефона ( не уверен, что такое вообще возможно)
3. Шаманить с Google FireBase, но я не уверен, что это правильный подход ибо в таком случае я буду хранить данные и в моей БД и в FireBase.

Мне кажется, что все мои варианты - не правильны. Я буду рад если вы укажете правильный путь и скинете пример кода для ясности.
На данный момент в качестве BackEnd стека я использую Spring + MySQL и просто по ссылке предоставляю json. Андроид приложение его парсит и выводит. Но идея, с постоянным "стучанием" в BackEnd мне не очень нравится.
Язык андроид-приложения (Java/Kotlin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging)
Тогда твой тригер отправить магический http запрос на [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions)
(!! Возможно это лишнее, и можно запустить FCM прямо с [твоего сервера](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server) )
Которые запустят рассылку(И само разошлет сообщение по всем андроидам), и создавать БД в Firebase не обязательно.

Comment: @(Valera Kvip)  Проблема в том, что FCM в больших объёмах не бесплатный.
А если я организовываю большое кол-во чатов, то я рискую разориться на старте.

Comment: @WBLord, 1. написано что бесплатно в любых объемах 2. " рискую разориться на старте." - за все так или иначе придется платить. На данный момент  FCM бесплатен - вот и пользуйся.

Comment: Благодарю, буду пробовать